# mp4 video won't play on Nexus 4

Tags: android, video

I'm developing an app that plays mp4 video from a webserver, but none of the videos play on Nexus 4 (JB 4.3). This includes opening the videos in chrome, or downloading them to the phone and playing them. They play fine on HTC One and Galaxy S4.

A video:
https://www.sundhed.dk/content/cms/30/20530_021-asthma-dan-h264-mov-640x360-16x9-mp4.mp4

Here's some [mediainfo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fj8mj6542t4yiw4/Screenshot%202013-10-30%2014.01.04.png).

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device doesn't support you video format/codec.

Comment: Turns out it is a problem with the encoding.